# Thymeleaf and Vue.js - why are js files are not showing up in chrome source tab

Tags: spring, google-chrome, vue.js, thymeleaf, vue-cli

After the vue app is built all files from the dist/assets/ directory are copied over to correct path on the server.  All correct assets show up in the chrome sources tab under assets directory except for the js directory and files.  App still loads and works correctly, but we're unable to view the vue related js files for debugging on frontend.

Why is the assets/js/ directory not showing up?

From pom.xml of Spring app:

```
<includes>
  <include>assets/css/</include>
  <include>assets/fonts/</include>
  <include>assets/js/</include>
  <include>assets/img/</include>
</includes>
```